# Fastest way to find all integers in array between bounds

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

What would be the fastest way to get all the values in an array that are between 2 bounds. Both bounds would be inclusive. In the array, there can be duplicates, and in that case it should return **all** values.

For example, if I had the array: `[1 1 3 3 4 6 7 7 8 10]` and the bounds `[2, 7]` the program would return `[3 3 4 6 7 7]`.

I know I could do a loop and go through every element to check if it's in the bounds, but I am wondering if there is a faster way. The array **is sorted** so I thought about doing a binary search but I'm not sure how that would work.

Thanks!

Comment: There is lots of way, and the difference in time would be tiny

Comment: I'm confused... `for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++) { System.out.println(arr[i]); }` - is that what you want?

Comment: Are bound given for values or for indexes?

Comment: If the array is sorted you just need to omit the values outside of the range. But that

Comment: Use binary search to find the lowest index where the value is greater than or equal to the lower bound.  Use binary search again to find the highest index where the value is less than or equal to the upper bound.

Comment: This question shows absolutely zero prior effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.binarySearch(int[], key)` to find the high and low boundary elements, whether they exist or not. Given bounds `low` and `high`, the `subRange()` method should do about what you want:

```
/* returns the index first/last occurrence of a value, or one past 
   where the element would have been if missing */
static int indexOf(int array[], int bound, boolean last) {
  int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, bound);
  if (last && index >= 0) {
    while (index < array.length && array[index] == bound) index++;
  }
  return index < 0 ? -index - 1 : index;
}

static int subRange(int a[], int low, int high) {
  return Arrays.copyOfRange(a, indexOf(a, low, false), indexOf(a, high, true));
}
```

The primary awkwardness is handling the upper bound (the `last == true` case) since `binarySearch` returns the index of the *first* element, so you need to scan through to find the last element. I'm pretty sure there is an off-by-one error in there somewhere, left as a surprise for the reader who copies it without understanding.

A small additional optimization is possible in that the second search could be restricted to the range to the right of the index found by the first search, using the version of `Arrays.binarySearch` that operates on a subrange of the array. If you wanted to get *really* hardcore, you could write your own custom binary search, that takes both elements at once, and searches on both at once: at the start of the search, for as long as the current midpoint is lower or higher than *both* the elements you are effectively narrowing the range for both elements almost for free (compared to a single value search). Once `mid` splits the low and high keys, you do separate binary searches using the current range as a starting point. This is especially useful when `low` and `high` are very close: effectively cutting the search time in half.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is sorted, you are looking for a slice in the middle of the array.
So you need to find the position of the lowest bound in the array, then the same for the upper bound (starting at the end). Array elements between these positions are the resulting array.

You basically cut off the unwanted numbers at the start and at the end:

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10};
    int low=2;
    int up=7;
    int lowIdx=0;
    int upIdx=arr.length-1;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        lowIdx = i;
        if(arr[i] >= low){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(arr[i] <= up){
            break;
        }
        upIdx = i;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, lowIdx, upIdx)));
```

[prints `[3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7]`](https://ideone.com/Nj7nel)

Is this easy? Not really. It's slightly complicated code that takes advantage of the fact that the array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just doing:

```
int[] arr = {1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10};
int min = 2;
int max = 7;
int[] result = IntStream.of(arr).filter(x -> x >= min && x <= max).toArray();
```

Another way of doing it, which is in many cases faster than `binarysearch` because of the need to iterate the entire array to find the last index, is to use a loop that only needs to iterate over half of the elements, with two lookups pr. loop-cycle:

```
        int minIndex = arr.length;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] >= min && i < minIndex)
                minIndex = i;
            int j = arr.length-i-1;
            if(arr[j] <= max && j > maxIndex)
                maxIndex = j;
        }
        int[] res = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,minIndex,maxIndex+1);
```